# Rearranging equation with algebra

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm having a difficult time showing that the two are equivalent:

$2(x_1-\theta)(1+(x_2-\theta)^2)+2(x_2-\theta)(1+(x_1-\theta)^2) = 2(\bar{x}-\theta)(1+(x_1-\theta)(x_2-\theta))$

I have multiplied out the first part of the right hand equation, and I have:

$2(x_1+x_1x_2^2-2x_1x_2\theta+x_1\theta^2-\theta-x_2^2\theta+2x_2\theta^2-\theta^3)$

However, I'm not sure how to rearrange the equation so that I can pull out a $(\bar{x}-\theta)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you manipulate carefully the expression, you should find that the equality holds if $$\bar{x}=x_1+x_2-\theta$$